# c# regex to match specific text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking to match all text in the format foo:12345 that is not contained within an HTML anchor.  For example, I'd like to match lines 1 and 3 from the following:

`foo:123456`

`<a href="http://www.google.com">foo:123456</a>`

`foo:123456`

I've tried these regexes with no success:

Negative lookahead attempt ( incorrectly matches, but doesn't include the last digit )

`foo:(\d+)(?!</a>)`

Negative lookahead with non-capturing grouping

`(?:foo:(\d+))(?!</a>)`

Negative lookbehind attempt ( wildcards don't seem to be supported )

`(?<!<a[^>]>)foo:(\d+)`

Comment: I assume your last example is meant to be `(?<!<a[^>]*>)foo:(\d+)` so that it will match more than just one character in the anchor tag.

Comment: This question is asked nearly every day...parsing HTML with regular expressions is almost always a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is usually not the best tool for the job, but if your case is very specific like in your example you could use:

```
foo:((?>\d+))(?!</a>)
```

Your first expression didn't work because `\d+` would backtrack till `(?!</a>)` matches. This can be fixed by not allowing `\d+` to backtrack, as above with help of an atomic/nonbacktracking group, or you could also make the lookahead fail in case `\d+` backtracks, like:

```
foo:((?>\d+))(?!</a>|\d)
```

Altho that is not as efficient.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it did fix the regex to work

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start analysing HTML like this then you probably want to actually parse HTML instead of using regular expressions. The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the usual first port of call. Using Regular Expressions it becomes hard to deal with things like `<a></a>foo:123456<a></a>` which of course should pull out the middle bit but its extremely hard to write a regex that will do that.

I should add that I am assuming that you do in fact have a block of HTML rather than just individual short strings such as your each line above. Partly I ruled it out becasue matching it if it is the only thing on the line is pretty easy so I figured you'd have got it if you wanted that. :)

Comment: That is a good point - I'll look into using that lib going forward.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that lookbehind will not work with differnt string length inside, you may work it out differently

for example

1. Find and mark all foo-s that are contained in anchor
2. Find and do your goal with all other
3. Remove marks

Answer (score 0):

This is prob a long winded way of doing this but you could simply bring back all occurences of foo:some digits then exclude them afterwards..

```
string pattern = @"foo:\d+ |" +
                 @"foo:\d+[<]";
```

Then use matchcollection

```
 MatchCollection m0 = Regex.Matches(file, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Then loop through each occurrence:

```
foreach (Match m in m0)
{
                 . . . exclude the matches that contain the "<"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use linq and treat the html like xml, for example:
 var query = MyHtml.Descendants().ToArray();
            foreach (XElement result in query)
            {

```
            if (Regex.IsMatch(result.value, @"foo:123456") && result.Name.ToString() != "a")
            {
               //do something...
            }
        }
```

perhaps there's a better way, but i don't know it...this seems pretty straight forward to me :P